# I need to use bubble sort to sort an array of structures from a file in C

Tags: arrays, c, file, sorting, structure

Okay, so i need to use bubble sort to sort an array of structures that i need to get form a file. I need to sort them based on char index (index is something like a student ID). I have a file precreated and there is 120 structures, now i need to create a bubble function that is going to sort the structures and print them out. And i need to call this function in switch case 1. Here is my code of how i tryed doing it.

This is my header

```
   typedef struct studenti
  {
    char index[10];
    char ime[20];
    char prezime[20];
    int kviz[10];
} studenti;

int init_load(studenti *studenti, FILE *file) {
    // pricati index, ime i prezime, ako ne ucita neko od navedenih program se zatvara
    if (3 != fscanf(file, "%9s%19s%19s", studenti->index, studenti->ime, studenti->prezime))
        return 0;

    char buffer[256];

    // ako je fajl prazan program se zavrsava
    if (fgetc(file) != '\n' || !fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file))
        return 0;

    // razdvaja string na osnovu linije "|"
    size_t i = 0;
    char *token = strtok(buffer, "|");

    // sacuva ocjene u studenti strukturu
    if (token) do {
        studenti->kviz[i++] = (int) strtol(token, NULL, 10);
    } while (i < 10 && (token = strtok(NULL, "|")));

    /* make sure we read enough ints, and our delimiting line is there. */
    if (i != 10 || !fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file) ||
            0 != strncmp(buffer, "----------", 10))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

void print_studenti()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("studenti_2022.txt", "r");
    studenti studenti;


    if (file) while (init_load(&studenti, file))
    {
        printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", studenti.index, studenti.ime, studenti.prezime);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d ", studenti.kviz[i]);
        printf("\n");
        putchar('\n');
    }

    fclose(file);


}

void poIndeksu()
{

    studenti *zamjena;
    int i,j;
    int n=120;

    while (init_load(&studenti, file))
    {

                for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
                {
                    for(j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
                    {
                        if(studenti[j].index > studenti[j+1].index)
                        {

                            zamjena = studenti[j];
                            studenti[j] = studenti[j+1];
                            studenti[j+1] = zamjena;

                        }
                    }
                }
                print_studenti();
            }

}
```

And here is my main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "student.h"
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{

    print_studenti();

    int opcija;
    printf("Kako zelite sortirati studente?\n ");
    printf("1 Po broju indexa\n 2 Po imenu\n 3 Po prezimenu\n 4 Po broju bodova iz kviza");
    printf("\n\nUnos: ");
    scanf("%d", &opcija);


    switch(opcija)
    {
        case 1:
            poIndeksu();
        break;

    /*  case 2:
        poImenu();
        break;

        case 3:
        poPrezimenu();
        break;

        case 4:
        poKvizu();
        break;

        default:
        printf("Pogresan unos!");
        break; */
    }


   return 0;

}
```

This is how the file looks like form where i need to get the data. The marked red ones are the indexes based on which i need to sort the file.

I am new to this so I guess I made a lot of mistakes.

Comment: You should show your attempt at writing your sorting function.

Comment: I did it's the 
void poIndeksu(); in my .h file

Comment: OK, in the question you mention `bubble` function. Please be consistent.

Comment: Okay mb I am new to all of this. Sorry.

Comment: You should not put function definitions in a header file.  Put declarations in a `*.h`, and put definitions in a `*.c`.

Comment: What does your input look like?  From the code, it looks like you expect there to always be a blank line after the `-------` line.  Is that the case?

Comment: The globals complicate things, but it looks like `print_studenti` closes `file`.  Then `init_load` tries to read from the file.  Those reads will fail, since the file has been closed.

Comment: Okay so i messed up really bad.
Yes you are right there should be blank line after the ------- line, because i don't want -------- to load with my structure